# Is this expression a well-established proverb or just a slight variation of a well-established one?

Tags: expressions, proverbs

I'm referring to this one:

*Any man who is his own translator has a fool for an editor.*

The resemblance that this expression bears to the one about [any individual who chooses to represent himself/herself in a legal case](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-man-who-is-his-own-lawyer-has-a-fool-for-a-client.html) is undeniable. Yet, even when the meaning of the latter expression is pretty clear to me, I'm not sure I get the point which whoever made up the translator/editor variant of the proverb was trying to make... I would be really glad if, in addition of getting an answer for the question in the title, you could help me **unravel** the meaning of the expression under consideration.

Let me thank you in advance for your learned replies.

Comment: There's also the probably even older [*He that is his own doctor, has a fool for his patient.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has+a+fool+for+his+patient%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). I can't easily find any pre-C20 references for yours - it seems more a latter-day triumph of style over substance/form over meaning. You can trot them out yourself though - *He that loves himself loves a fool*.

Comment: "... it seems more a latter-day triumph of style over substance/form over meaning." -- Care to elaborate?

Comment: I said "latter-day" because the earliest *fool+editor* I can find is [*the therapist who tries to evaluate his own writing has a fool for an editor*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+therapist+who+tries+to+evaluate+his+own+writing%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) in 1979. And it's style over substance because in practice (as you've obviously discovered yourself) your exact version means little or nothing - it has the *form* of a pithy/witty observation embodying some useful truth, but that's about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a proverb in its own right. It's a play on the well-established legal proverb, "A man who is his own lawyer has a fool for a client".

It appears to mean, "Only a foolish editor would allow an author to be his own translator".

As you've identified, the mapping from the legal proverb doesn't really work.

Here's why:

- In the legal proverb, the man who is his own lawyer is of necessity his own client: only 1 person is involved. That's the joke.
- In this version, two parties seem to be involved: the editor and the author/translator.

Alternatively, it's possible that (by analogy to the legal proverb) the author is trying to say that a foolish author is both his own editor and his own translator.

Either way, someone is trying to be witty and failing.

Is this in reference to "[A Mathematical letter from Engels to Marx](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/rarm/engels.html)"? If so then - if the "Translator's Note" and "Author's Note" are both by Raimi, which is my understanding - he seems to be apologising for possible deficiencies in his translation from German to English, by saying that he is foolish in taking on the triple role of author, editor and translator.

Comment: Yes, I came across the said expression in that web page! Thank you very much for such a detailed reply...

Answer (score 2):

A man who is his own lawyer has a fool for a client. has been around for a very long time.

So it's a variation on a well-known saying. But I wouldn't waste time trying to unravel it, since the relationship between editor and translator is not really analogous to lawyer/client.

Alternatively, it could be a witty poke at a particular publishing house, where the editor expects the author to be his own translator (thus dooming the book to poor sales and perhaps ridicule in the foreign land, if the author does not have an excellent command of that tongue.)

Comment: "The relationship between editor and translator is not really analogous to lawyer/client..." -- EXACTLY, even though the expression in question is totally analogous to the one 'bout the individual who is his/her own lawyer, the relationship 'twixt editor and translator is not that similar to the one 'twixt lawyer and client. In a sense, that observation is the very source of my query! You have hit the nail sooo right on the head, TRomano...